# Chrome refuses to display iframe, but other browsers do

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe

I want to display a web page within a frame. This page has a redirect in front of it, that navigates to another web page for authentication. This other page doesn't allow its content to be displayed in an iframe which is completely fine for me. If the user is already authenticated, then he will not be redirected to that page. The current behavior is like follows:

1. If the user is not authenticated, the iframe will show "Refuse to display content" on all browsers, because the request it's redirected to that other web page for authentication.
2. If the user is already authenticated, the iframe will work on Edge,IE and Firefox, but not on Chrome, where the same message will be displayed.

Can this be solved within the Chrome settings?

**Update**

The messages are the following:

In incognito mode the iframe looks like this. I blurred the domain name, but the hidden text is the page at which I'm redirected, the one responsible for authentication.

[image]

In normal mode (no incognito). Now the hidden text is the domain which I'm trying to reach with my iFrame.
[image]

Comment: Check the top url bar section beside bookmark icon. It may be asking to enable to iframe

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: @brk The iframe is enabled.

Comment: @Barmar no errors in the console

Comment: Please post the code it uses to determine if it's already authenticated.

Comment: @Barmar is an external application, at which I don't have access to

Comment: Then the problem is with that application.

Comment: @Barmar is working fine on other browsers. The problem is not that application, but Chrome.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220370/discussion-between-georgian-stan-and-barmar).

Comment: What kind of help are you looking for? If you can't modify the JavaScript, what do you expect to do?

Comment: @Barmar 
I'm trying to understand the problem. Why this behavior on Chrome and not other browsers? And if I can bypass this from Chrome settings.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is from Chrome, due to the latest security updates. Other browsers will follow this behavior in the future.

[https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592\](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592%5C)

And to bypass this in Chrome, here are the steps:

https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site/test-debug